# Hyperledger Fabric - Unable to resolve host - when issue an asset to chaincode

Tags: java, docker, networking, hyperledger-fabric

Currently I have written a java application which should create an asset via the Hyperledger Fabric SDK.

The fabric network (peers, orderers, channel etc..) all run in a VM. The java application is on the same VM. When I try to create an Asset, using the java application (uses SDK), I get the following error:

[image: st]

I also get another error: "Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.....etc.."

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check your dns resolving and network

Comment: How can i check the dns?